# Creating mailboxes/email accounts for users

Tags: email

We are building an rss reader platform and would like to offer users the option to setup their own email account on our domain for subscribing to feeds.  Using google/rackspace email at $2-$5/user is not viable.  Does anyone know of a stable way to either install some email server software, or some other way to create sub accounts to solve this problem?

Comment: Thanks for all your amazing help.  lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use http://postmarkapp.com.  They have incoming options.

Comment: I didn't find this feature in the documentation. Do you know if they even have this feature? If not, do you know any tools that do this?